# DateTimeOffset Stored as GMT Convert To Central Time

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, date

Is there a way in T-SQL to Convert GMT To Central Time that compensates for Daylight Saving.

It seems that `SWITCHOFFSET` only accepts a string in the format `[+|-]TZH:TZM` or a signed integer (of minutes) that represents the time zone offset, and is assumed to be daylight-saving aware and adjusted.

Comment: I don't understand why you want to do it on SQL Server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not easy to do, there are big issues relating to timezone conversion. I.e. what happens if you want to convert a date from last August, you'd need to know if DST was applicable when the time was recorded.

This is fixed in the latest version by using the **datetimeoffset** type. This records the UTC time plus the offset in force at when the datetime was recorded. This makes it much easier to work with timezones.

Here's a link [The death of datetime](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bartd/archive/2009/03/31/the-death-of-datetime.aspx)

Comment: The problem I have is that I am looking for records between 2 times that are specified in Central Time and the Data is stored in a datetimeoffset in GMT time, so it is the DST issues that are causing me problems

Comment: If both are stored in a datetimeoffset field then SQL should be comparing them correctly using the stored UTC datetime. As Bart says in the link i just added "SQL will do the right thing"